# React header design with materialUI or bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-ui

I want to design the header of react application. I'm using react materialUI and bootstrap 3.3.7. I think to use bootstrap for header design. How to proceed further or can we make this using react materialUI?

Also, Need to make this header responsive.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a way to create that header with bootstrap

Comment: @cwanjt Not with bootstrap, using materialUI.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no inbuilt Header in the material-ui for react, but there are components like Toolbar and App-bar which you can customize according to your requirement and use them like header

- http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toolbar
- http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

But you will get same responsive header in bootstrap.

PS: All components are responsive by default, but keep in mind you cannot add media query to those components.